# dcast with multiple variables in val.var option

Tags: r

I am using the `dcast` function:

```
summary <- dcast(DB1, 
                 REGION_ID + REGION_NAME ~ STATUS,
                 fun.aggregate = sum, 
                 value.var = "SALES")
```

I am trying to use the two variables in value.var but getting an error. Below is the syntax:

```
summary <- dcast(DB1, 
                 REGION_ID + REGION_NAME ~ STATUS,
                 fun.aggregate = sum, 
                 value.var = c("SALES","PROFIT"))
```

Comment: Can you show the error and also a small reproducible example

Comment: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: is `DB1` a `data.table`.  i.e. `dcast(setDT(DB1), ...`. it is possible that the DB1 is a data.frame and you are using `dcast` from `reshape2` instead from `data.table`

Comment: Hi, if we keep one variable then it is working.                                                               
For example, the first query,                                                                                         The output will be       REGION_ID  REGION_NAME URBAN RURAL.  As we can observe, the SALES name is not being displayed. Since we are using two columns in the second query, is it creating a problem?

Comment: Pleease check my solutiion below.  Your issue is because the DB1 is data.frane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when we are using `reshape2::dcast` instead of `data.table::dcast` because `reshape2::dcast` doesn't support more than one `value.var`.

The documentation for `?reshape2::dcast` gives

> value.var - name of column which stores values, see guess_value for default strategies to figure this out.

while in `?data.table::dcast` it is

> value.var - Name of the column whose values will be filled to cast. Function guess() tries to, well, guess this column automatically, if none is provided. Cast multiple value.var columns simultaneously by passing their names as a character vector. See Examples.

---

With a small reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
dcast(mtcars, vs + am ~ carb, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = c('mpg', 'disp'))
```

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In dcast(mtcars, vs + am ~ carb, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = c("mpg",

If we convert to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(as.data.table(mtcars), vs + am ~ carb, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = c('mpg', 'disp'))
#   vs am mpg_1 mpg_2 mpg_3 mpg_4 mpg_6 mpg_8 disp_1 disp_2 disp_3 disp_4 disp_6 disp_8
#1:  0  0   0.0  68.6  48.9  63.1   0.0     0    0.0 1382.0  827.4 2082.0      0      0
#2:  0  1   0.0  26.0   0.0  57.8  19.7    15    0.0  120.3    0.0  671.0    145    301
#3:  1  0  61.0  47.2   0.0  37.0   0.0     0  603.1  287.5    0.0  335.2      0      0
#4:  1  1 116.4  82.2   0.0   0.0   0.0     0  336.8  291.8    0.0    0.0      0      0
```

---

In the OP's code, it would be

```
summary_out <- dcast(setDT(DB1), 
                 REGION_ID + REGION_NAME ~ STATUS,
                 fun.aggregate = sum, 
                 value.var = c("SALES","PROFIT"))
```